# Google Analytics - Content grouping - Regex fix

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics

This is our URL structure:

```
http://www.disabledgo.com/access-guide/the-university-of-manchester/176-waterloo-place-2

http://www.disabledgo.com/access-guide/kingston-university/coombehurst-court-2

http://www.disabledgo.com/access-guide/kings-college-london/franklin-wilkins-building-2

http://www.disabledgo.com/access-guide/redbridge-college/brook-centre-learning-resource-centre
```

I am trying to create a list of groups based on the client names

```
/access-guide/[this bit]/...
```

So I can have a performance list of all our clients.

This is my regex:

```
/access-guide/(.*universit(y|ies)|.*colleg(e|es))/
```

I want it to group anything that has university/ies or college/es in it, at any point within that client name section of the URL.

At the moment, my current regex will only return groups that are X-University:

```
Durham-University
Plymouth-University
Cardiff-University 
etc.
```

What does the regex need to be to have the list I'm looking for?

Do I need to have something at the end to stop it matching things after the client name? E.g. `([^/]+$)`?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Try [`/access-guide/[^/]*(universit(y|ies)|colleges?)/`](https://regex101.com/r/oU0hT1/1). The `[^/]*` will enforce a restraint on where `university/college` are located.

Comment: Based on this: [*You can extract pages by Page URL, Page Title, or Screen Name. Identify each one with a regex capture group (Analytics uses the first capture group for each expression)*](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167&vid=1-635784241538251930-2972435195#extract), my mistake is that I placed the capturing group around the wrong pattern. Looks like it should be `/access-guide/([^/]*(universit(y|ies)|colleges?))`. Pay attention at the first capturing group in the online regex tester, that is what you will get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon your needs you may want to do:

```
/access-guide/([^/]*(?:university|universities|college|colleges)[^/]*)/
```

This will match names even if "university" or "college" is not at the end of the string. For example "[college-of-the-ozarks](http://www.cofo.edu)" Note the non-capturing internal parenthesis, that should probably be used no matter what solution you go with, as you don't want to just match the word "university" or "college"

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://regex101.com/r/vR2mF3/1)

Additionally, I don't know what may be in your but if you may have compound words you want to eliminate using a `\b` may be advisable. For instance if you don't want to match "[miskatonic-postcollege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miskatonic_University)" you may want to do something like this:

```
/access-guide/([^/]*\b(?:university|universities|college|colleges)\b[^/]*)/
```

Comment: I'm going to try this version today and see what happens tomorrow thank you

Comment: Testing it in the REGEX tester, the results are more promising, we'll see tomorrow.

Comment: @aden From your question I'm pretty confident this is what you want. If you need syntax clarification to help you with customization, let me know.

Comment: Thanks johnathan, i've just had a quick look and i think GA has taken to the new REGEX, however i'm getting some very strange results still, whenever i have a university, or anything under that particular content group, it won't show details before the 3rd of september. So where the groups should have pageviews in the 1000s, there are only say 14. Very confused.

Comment: @aden Hmmm... my expertise is with regexes. If the problem is that the capture is returning an unexpected result I can help but beyond that I'd be a little out of my depth. I'd recommend accepting this answer and opening a new question to call upon the wisdom of stack overflow on the issue.

Comment: I think i'll have to do that, before i do, i have another similar issue. Where this is for universities/colleges, we also do councils and hospitals. I've tried applying the same REGEX structure but for health and local authorities it gives me very random results. All i'm doing is swapping out "university" for council etc, i'm not sure why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @aden I can't be of much help to you without seeing specifics. But I can tell you that my first step would be to plug the regex and the inputs into http://www.regex101.com and try it out. If that doesn't work I'd again suggest a new question so you can post all the information in a well formatted manner.

Comment: @aden Hey if you post new questions on those issues could you link them in a comment here? I'd be interested in the resolution as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the client name section of the URL is after the `access-guid/` and before the next `/`:

```
http://www.disabledgo.com/access-guide/the-university-of-manchester/176-waterloo-place-2
                                      |----------------------------|
```

you need to use a negated character class to only match `university` before the regex reaches that rightmost `/` boundary.

As per the [Reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167&vid=1-635784241538251930-2972435195#extract):

> You can extract pages by Page URL, Page Title, or Screen Name. Identify each one with a regex capture group (Analytics uses the first capture group for each expression)

Thus, you can use

```
/access-guide/([^/]*(universit(y|ies)|colleges?))
              ^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU0hT1/3).

The regex matches

- `/access-guide/` - leftmost boundary, matches `/access-guide/` literally
- `[^/]*` - any character other than `/` (so we still remain in that customer section)
- `(universit(y|ies)|colleges?)` - `university`, or `universities, or`college`or`colleges` literally. Add more if needed.

Comment: Escape the backslashes if necessary (but I do not think it is required in GA ).

Comment: Thanks for your speedy comment! The Demo definitely looks like it's going to work, i've added it in, we'll see on monday when google has some time to accept it (takes a while normally, someone said 24hrs). Thank you though!

Comment: Just FYI: I have just found that I mispasted the regex from regex101 to the answer. The final `/` should not be there. You just do not need to search for the `/` rightmost boundary.

Comment: Most definitely i will do! thank you! PS i copied it straight from the demo so I didn't have the / on it but thanks! :)

Comment: So i've got in this morning, checked analytics, and it still hasn't worked, there is a huge chunk (not set) at the top, and then all the URLs that have been grouped are the ones that end with "-university". So "plymouth-university" "Cardiff-University" etc...

Comment: Well, so far, the groups are visible (some what) but i have several issues still. At the top i have (Not Set) still, this has metrics available for whatever time period i choose, the rest, only produce results for the last 3 weeks or so, as the days go on, the numbers increase, am i right in saying, anything that is in a group, needs to accrue data over time? so to have good results, i need to wait X amount of time for it to be visible. Does that sound right?

Comment: I think yes, and you actually can have a feel of how the setup is performing by looking at the current results (however small they can be at the beginning).